# CLTK Module in Python

Tags: python, module, nlp

I have just begun using the CLTK (classical languages toolkit) NLT module in Python, and wish to use it as a lemmatizer for Latin text. Every time I make the initial step of attempting to import a corpus, I get the following error:

> from cltk.corpus.utils.importer import CorpusImporter

I get the following error:

File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cltk.corpus'.

I installed the cltk module using "pip3 install cltk" on Ubuntu, but dir(cltk) doesn't recognise "corpus" as an attribute of cltk.

Comment: Can you run pip list on the terminal/virtual environment of your python installation and see if the library is listed there?

Answer (score 3):

This is because CLTK has changed its major version (version 1 now) and the new doc is here https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/.

For the previous doc, you can still read there https://legacy.cltk.org/en/latest/

You can still install the previous major version by doing `pip install cltk==0.1.121`

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for the usage of the new CLTK 1.0+ available here https://github.com/cltk/cltk/blob/master/notebooks/CLTK%20Demonstration.ipynb.

Currently the latin pipeline supports the following tasks:

- LatinNormalizeProcess
- LatinStanzaProcess
- LatinEmbeddingsProcess
- StopsProcess
- LatinNERProcess
- LatinLexiconProcess

(see https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/languages.html#latin)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29822907)